# Selecting features in layer by attribute in field and exporting them in another shapefile using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, attribute-table, select

I need to export some features inside a shapefile according to an attribute (e.g. field_value = 20). I know how to do it without ModelBuilder.
I need it to do it in ModelBuilder because a have many shapefiles to make this same process and with the same criteria to select features.

Answer (score 1):

In ModelBuilder you can add the tool "Select (Analysis)" and then enter your SQL query in the tool in ModelBuilder. You can integrate that into your model from there.

Comment: after selecting in each feacture class (because I'm iterating trough feature classes) what tool should be proper to export what's selected.

Comment: Select (Analysis) is the tool that exports them.  The summary of the tool reads: "Extracts features from an input feature class or input feature layer, typically using a select or Structured Query Language (SQL) expression and stores them in an output feature class."  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/select.htm